# glGetError() returns 1

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am using QT 4.8.4 and drawing OpenGL on QGraphicsScene background. The problem is that I am getting **invalid return from glGetError()**. My code snippet:

```
while (GLenum err = glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << err;        
}
```

On application output I get a lot of lines with **number 1**

From the documentation I see possible values are:

GL_NO_ERROR, GL_INVALID_ENUM, GL_INVALID_VALUE, GL_INVALID_OPERATION, GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION, GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY, GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW, GL_STACK_OVERFLOW

which are defined as 0, 0x0500, 0x0501, 0x0502, 0x0503, 0x0504, 0x0505, 0x0506.

## How is it possible I get the 1 instead of a proper error code?

This started to happen when I wrapped my native OpenGL drawing code with QT's:

```
painter->beginNativePainting();
...
painter->endNativePainting();
```

PS: The multiple 1's are from multiple draw calls and not from the loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide a bigger sample of your code and the output you are seeing?  It's not quite clear what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you Derek! As this question has been answered correctly it is clear that this had nothing to do with the context (it might be better to remove unnecessary details instead of adding new :) ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
GLenum err;
while ( ( err = glGetError() ) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << err;        
}
```

Your `!=` was getting evaluated before the `=`.

Comment: Good idea to limit that loop and handle a limit reached accordingly; otherwise, the observer could get strung out for a while watching an endless stream of 1282s (0x502, GL_INVALID_OPERATION.)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the following line doesn't do what you want:

```
GLenum err = glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR
```

It *first* evaluates `glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR`, and *then* assigns it to `err`.

That's why it's *always* a good idea to spend 2 more characters in your source code:

```
(GLenum err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR
```

Additional advice: Use `glewGetErrorString` if you are already using the `glew` library:

```
std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(err);
```

Comment: You are correct. I'm not using GLEW, but I have implemented a more reasonable error log, I just didn't show it here.